# How do I suppress the method name from my xml in a WCF Web Service?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

I do not want my web method name as part of the hierarchy in my XML.  I strictly want the object that was passed in to be encapsulated in a SOAP envelope, then have an empty Header, and in the Body I want the first sub-element to be of the type of object I'm passing in (in this case, ns:QueryRequest).

When I had an .asmx web page, I was getting two extra levels in my hierarchy (i.e., the web method name and the name of the object being passed into the web method).  So, beneath Body, I had GetData -> actualData -> ns:QueryRequest.  I was able to suppress the first two elements by creating a [SoapDocumentMethod] on the web method and setting ParameterStyle=SoapParameterStyle.Bare.

I'm creating a WCF web page now for a comparison.  I specified [XmlSerializerFormat] beneath [OperationContract] on the interface and this resolved my namespace issues.  I tried implementing [WebInvoke] and [WebGet] beneath that, with a BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, but it isn't suppressing the GetData method name in the interface.  I need the first element beneath Body to be ns:QueryRequest and not GetData.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a [MessageContract(IsWrapped=false)] for the input parameter and a separate one for the output.  This will suppress the unwanted root element.

Answer (score 0):

[SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare]

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**